# Settings and Getting Session Variables stored in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm basically trying to create a class that holds all the session information, then set and get it at will.

here is my call `Session["SessionInformation"] = new SessionVar.UserSession();`

and here is that class

```
public static class SessionVar
{

public class UserSession
{


    public string FullName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string HomeURL
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool ValidUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CountID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
}
```

Lets say in this example I have a comboBox called CountID_ComboBox and on SelectedIndexChanged I want to set the users specific `Session["SessionInformation"] CountID` to the value of the combobox.  How is that done?

```
protected void CountID_ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //set the session variable here
}
```

Also, is there a way to foreach loop the strings in the class.  Basically I want to see if any of those variables in that class is null.

Comment: First try writing some code... your class does absolutely nothing for now. From your question Im' not sure if you're not trying to re-invent the wheel though...

Comment: @Bartdude it does what I want it to do, it gets and sets strings...

Comment: @Bartdude the point is to have a set of session variables that is manageable in a nice clean fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right, but have you tried this: `((SessionVar.UserSession)Session["SessionInformation"]).CountID = CountID_ComboBox.SelectedValue`?

Comment: @AndreCalil I think that might be it....

Comment: Why aren't you using Session[] in your getters and setters ? I probably missed the point of the question...

Comment: @Bartdude why would I have to when I'm creating a session instance of that class and then referencing that Session instance, see Andre comment

Comment: @Bartdude He doesn't need to. Keeping that instance on the session will manage all the values on the heap, associated with the `UserSession` object. It's a bit confusing, but that's a nice approach for big projects, when it's a hell to manage session use

Comment: @AndreCalil preach on!  `when its a hell to manage session use

Comment: @AndreCalil when you have like a 10 page form fill out you need something like this.  But how do you foreach object in the session?

Comment: @Mike Let me know and I'll post an answer. I have some more ideas =)

Comment: @AndreCalil Go ahead and post i'm sure thats it.

Comment: @Mike I still don't get the "foreach object in the session" question...

Comment: @Both of you : indeed, I missed the point of the question :-)
Now the question is how to loop over properties of UserSession class, if i'm not mistaken Andre

Comment: @AndreCalil well for example lets say CountID was set via the combobox but the user never sets HomeURL via a differernt combobox.  I want to be able to say hey you missed these things!  For example they user might have filled out 20 out of the 30 required fields

Comment: @AndreCalil I guess I lost you.

Comment: @Mike now you got your full answer =)

Comment: @Mike any feedback, so far?

Answer (score 2):

So you've created this strongly typed `UserSession` class to handle your session variables. That's nice, specially if you have a big project, with lots of forms and (junior) developers.

You already know the most important part: for each new session, we'll have one, *and only one* `UserSession` object.

Now, let's move on to the part where you actually use it. You can retrieve the object's reference using `((SessionVar.UserSession)Session["SessionInformation"])`. Let's dive into it:

1. `Session["something"]` returns an object
2. You want your `UserSession` object
3. We cast it using `((SessionVar.UserSession)Session["SessionInformation"])` and your done!

Now, let's say that, later on, you decide to move that object from the session to the viewstate (I'm **not** saying that this is a good idea, mind you). If you have that code scattered around your project, then it'll be a pain to manage that change.

So, the idea is to have a **base page**, from which all your pages will inherit. Something like:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
...
}
```

And you place the code to retrieve your `UserSession` there, like:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public UserSession CurrentUserSession
    {
        get
        {
            UserSession userSession = null;

            if (Session["UserSession"] == null)
            {
                userSession = new UserSession();
                Session["UserSession"] = userSession;
            }
            else
                userSession = (UserSession)Session["UserSession"];

            return userSession;
        }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

**Bonus**: note that, on the code above, I'm suggesting a way to ensure that you get one and only one object for the current user.

Finally, in order to **get a list of the `string` properties that are empty**, you can use the following method (place it inside `UserSession`):

```
    public List<string> GetEmptyStringAttributes()
    {
        List<string> emptyStringAttributes = new List<string>();

        Type type = this.GetType();

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(String))
            {
                string value = property.GetValue(this) as string;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    emptyStringAttributes.Add(property.Name);
            }
        }

        return emptyStringAttributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Jr Developer remarks.....inferring that jr developers will have dozens of disjoint scalar values all over the place..using Session like a global variable holder.   :<

Comment: Andre i'm getting some issues with the iteration part Error 21 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(object, object[])' has some invalid argument

Comment: @Mike Where have you put the `GetEmptyStringAttributes` method?

Comment: @Mike How are things going? May I help you any further?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't find the combo box from your code behind, I'll use sender just to be sure we have the correct control.

```
var cBox = (RadComboBox)sender;
(SessionVar.UserSession)Session["SessionInformation"].CountID = cBox.SelectedValue;
```

It seems like the root of your question is actually about [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).